# I followed a Youtube video to do a water effect on a plane. The first time I did it, it worked nicely. The second and third time it failed

Tags: shader-nodes, bump

as mentioned in the title I followed a Youtube video showing how to make a water effect on a plane. It basically was just create a plane and then add *Noise Texture* and *Bump* nodes.

The first time I did it, it worked.

The second time I did it, it didn't worked.

I played around and discovered if I make the plane around 5 meters in size, the textures show up.
The third time it didn't work. I tried scaling the plane, played with the *Noise Texture* parameters of *Detail* and *Roughness*, played with the *Bump* parameters of *Strength* and *Distance*. Nothing happened.

I am guessing it just some setting I forgot to apply... Can anyone help?
I attached screenshots of the overall, shader editor and 3D view.

[image]

Many thanks!

[image: overall view]
[image: shader editor]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: please teach me how to share file. thanks

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or another platform like workupload (and share the link)

Comment: i tried to upload blend file. hopefully i did it right.

Comment: Here is what I see when I open your file, it seems to work fine, what is the problem? https://zupimages.net/up/23/41/tjy7.jpg

Comment: this is what i see. i cannot understand where the problem is.. https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=23/41/xv3y.jpg

Comment: OK that's weird I don't know what's happening, I hope someone will guess